# android cannot open downloaded file

Tags: android

I successfully download a pdf file from the internet and then I open the downloads folder using the following Intent:

```
Intent pdfFileIntent = new Intent();
pdfFileIntent.setAction(DownloadManager.ACTION_VIEW_DOWNLOADS);
ctx.startActivity(pdfFileIntent);
```

This code is located within the onReceive() method of a BroadcastReceiver I created to deal with download complete events.
The download is complete and successful (I can see the download status in the downloads folder, which is opened right after the download is complete, as expected). However, when I click the newly downloaded file, another dialog pops up which requests me to select the application with which the file will be opened (I can select either Adobe Reader or Quickoffice). When I select Adobe Reader, I get the error : "The document path is not valid" and when I select Quickoffice, I get the error: "File cannot be opened".

This is terribly annoying especially because the downloads folder and the download process and management of downloaded files is completely out of my hands - Android is aware of the files in the downloads directory when it presents them to me, so how can it be that it doesn't pass a valid path? What is going on?
To make things clear, I didn't specify any path in my code - Android chose the path in which to save the file. And I can even see that the file has a reasonable size in KBs, which means it's not empty and it's definitely a pdf file (.pdf extension).

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: after downloading..go to downloads folder (not from your app) using a file browser and check if it is opening or not..

Comment: Thanks bakriOnFire. The fact is that the downloaded file doesn't appear in the Downloads folder when I navigate to it using the file explorer of my device... maybe it's in a different folder? Still why I can see the file in the displayed Activity? If it's there that means that Android recognizes its existence, not so?

Comment: post ur code that u use to download and save in downloads folder..

Comment: Hi bakriOnFire. As I replied to Thorsten Dittmar, the file does open on another device with Polaris Office, which suggests you can trust me that my code is ok. But for some reason, I can't open it on my device and I don't know why.

Comment: can you post the download file code??

Comment: Put any other pdf file in downloads in mobile. First try opening it from file explorer in mobile if its opening then try opening it using your code.

Answer (score 1):

> And I can even see that the file has a reasonable size in KBs, which means it's not empty and it's definitely a pdf file (.pdf extension).

The fact that a file has the PDF extension doesn't necessarily make it a valid PDF file! Move the file to your PC and see whether you can open it there. You may have a bug in the code performing the download, causing some invalid content to be written to the file.

Comment: Actually, I tried opening downloaded pdf files on another device which has Polaris Office installed and it works fine on that device. It's definitely the pdf I'm expecting. But on my device it just doesn't open with the errors above.

Comment: By the way, the original device (on which the errors occur) is an Android 2.3.5 OS, Samsung Galaxy Young (1) device, and the device which succeeds in opening the file is an Android 4.0.1 OS, Samsung Galaxy 2 device. Hope that helps.